# unexpected '}' while using SQL and PHP for graphs

Tags: php, sql, mysql, graph

I'm coding a graph from SQL using PHP. I've got this code and it doesn't seem to execute. I thought the code was right but apprently it's not.

the code is:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatefrompng ("graphtemp.png");
$red = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 0, 0);
$black = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_query("USE database");
$optionsquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brands");
$numoptions = mysql_num_rows($optionsquery);
$pollquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories");
$numvotes = mysql_num_rows($pollquery);
$xval = 30;
$barwidth = floor(300/$numoptions);
for ($i=0;$i<=($numoptions-1);$i++) 
{
    $voteoption = mysql_result($optionsquery,$i,'name');
    $votevalue = mysql_result($optionsquery,$i,'value');
    $currentnumquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE vote='$votevalue'");
    $currentnum = mysql_num_rows($currentnumquery);
    $per = floor(($currentnum/$numvotes)*184);
    $rper = floor(($currentnum/$numvotes)*100);
    imagefilledrectangle ($im, $xval, (200-$per), ($xval+$barwidth), 200, $red);
    imagerectangle ($im, $xval, (200-$per), ($xval+$barwidth), 200, $black);
    imagestring ($im, 1, ($xval+($barwidth/2)), 205, $voteoption, $black);
    imagestring ($im, 2, ($xval+($barwidth/2)), ((200-$per)-15), "$rper%", $bla);
    $xval+=($barwidth+10)
}
imagepng($im);
?>
```

When I use this I get the error:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/user/public_html/graph.php on line 27
```

---

Thanks guys! This code doesn't seem to work here is the error log. I'm learning PHP and SQL as well so any help is appreciated. - http://pastebin.com/Zw18Afne

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `($barwidth+10)`

Comment: Do you even read the errors, there there for a reason, the answer is in fornt of you if you look closely.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Why would he bother? Just copy and paste into SO, no brain activity required.

Answer (score 2):

```
 1. <?php
 2. header ("Content-type: image/png");
 3. $im = imagecreatefrompng ("graphtemp.png");
 4. $red = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 0, 0);
 5. $black = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
 6. mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
 /*
     SNIP
 */
 24.    imagestring ($im, 1, ($xval+($barwidth/2)), 205, $voteoption, $black);
 25.    imagestring ($im, 2, ($xval+($barwidth/2)), ((200-$per)-15), "$rper%", $bla);
 26.    $xval+=($barwidth+10)
 27. }
 28. imagepng($im);
 29. ?>
```

ok so let's take a look at the error then:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/user/public_html/graph.php on line 27

Ok the error is basically saying, that PHP Found a `}` of witch it didn't expect, the reason for this is that php skips spaces, new lines and any invisible character from the code and then interprets the code.

So PHP Sees you code like this

```
$xval+=($barwidth+10)}imagepng($im);
//                   ^
```

But as you can see, i have placed an arrow where php reaches and says, what.. there should not be a `}` here :/

Within PHP Each line of command should be closed with a `;` so that PHP knows that the end of that bit of code, and the second is not part of the first.

```
26.    $xval+=($barwidth+10); // ; here
27. }
28. imagepng($im);
29. ?>
```

placing the colon here tells php to move on to the next command.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon after

```
$xval+=($barwidth+10)
```

Comment: If it's a new error, then it should be a new question. But given all those "not an image resource, boolean given" means that at some point one of the GD calls (the image*() functions) failed and returned a boolean FALSE, which didn't check for and kept reusing later.